# azure adding weird characters when transforming config

Tags: azure, web-config, azure-web-app-service, web-config-transform

I have a Web.config and and a transform called Web.AzureDev.config

I have the following section in both:

web.config:

```
  <elmah>
    <security allowRemoteAccess="1" />
    <errorLog type="Elmah.XmlFileErrorLog, Elmah" logPath="~/App_Data/Elmah" />
  </elmah>
```

Web.AzureDev.config

```
  <elmah>
    <errorMail xdt:Transform="Insert" from="xxxx@xxxx.com" to="yyy@yyyy.com" subject="Dev Exception" async="true" smtpPort="0">
    </errorMail>
  </elmah>
```

When I deploy to Azure, no matter what I do, it always produces the elmah tag like so:

```
<elmah>&gt;
    <security allowRemoteAccess="1" /><errorLog type="Elmah.XmlFileErrorLog, Elmah" logPath="~/App_Data/Elmah" />
    <errorMail from="xxxx@xxxx.com" to="yyyy@yyyy.com" subject="Dev Exception" async="true"
      smtpPort="0">
    </errorMail>
</elmah>
```

Why does it do this? And why only on Azure? Where is this `&gt;` coming from? I don't have any extra angle brackets. I have same thing in other config transforms for another server, and it doesn't behave like so. In fact, I have other tags like elmah which do similar insert transforms within them. So why only Elmah?

**UPDATE:**

I changed elmah to belmah in both the files and the transformation was completely fine. So it seems it's allergic to the name "elmah" somehow when transforming?

Comment: &gt; is the entity code for ' > ' in HTML.
[Source](http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html_entities.asp)

Comment: Azure itself would not do any transforms. What are you using to publish/deploy the site?

Comment: @JustinPatten I'm just having it pull from a branch in bitbucket repo...

Comment: actually it does it even when I publish it using VS deploy tool manually.

Comment: when i publish it locally using the "FileSystem", it works fine! So I suspect it has something to do with publish to Azure.

Comment: In theory, if you publish to Azure from Visual Studio, the build/config process is the same as if you are writing to the local file system. Both will create the files, but, in the Azure option, it pushes those to Azure. My only theory is that there is some character that is not visible, due to encoding, that is being picked up by Azure. Can you completely delete that section from the web.config and applicable transforms and then re-add it? Do not use copy/paste

Comment: I did that already, and it doesn't work. Also, like I said, just changing that section to belmah seems to make it work. So I am really suspecting that something with the name elmah is triggering it.

Comment: When deploying to Azure from the repoistory, Kudu could be performing the web.config transform. Have you tried setting up the SCM_BUILD_ARGS setting for the project? See https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/1053

Comment: yep I have that set to -p:PublishProfile=AzureDev which corresponds to my config transform name.

Answer (score 0):

While a bug with the publish functionality is possible, please confirm that you haven't mistakenly inserted a special character in the .config files, and that your line endings are consistent

Comment: It doesn't matter anymore. I've switched to deploying via BitBucket and it works perfectly fine.